# Do I have to keep object file's relative directory path intact when linking?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make, ld

If I have source files in src/ and src/a/, do the object files generated from these source files generated from src/a/ have to be in obj/a/ if I'm putting my object files from src/ into obj?

If not does the linker just look at the last part of the filename in #include statements?

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't have to be. But you may find it easier to debug linkage problems if your object directory structure mimics your sources.

In fact you can order make to arrange it any way which works for you. Just tell all the rules where to find what.

> If not does the linker just look at the last part of the filename in
>   #include statements?

No, the linker has no knowledge of `include` directive. That is only part of preprocessing.